# Is there a REST API to monitor Devcie to Cloud data like in Device explorer

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have Successfully posted data from device to cloud using REST API. But i want to monitor that data using an API like We do in device explorer by selecting device ID and setting connection string.
Is there a way to monitor that using any REST API.

Comment: There is no REST API endpoint to pull-up (consume) the device-to-cloud messages on the service-facing side.

Comment: Then is there any way to monitor events without Device explorer or extension given in VScode.

Comment: Hopefully what you are looking for is EventGrid integration in Azure IoT Hub. You can get notified for various events like DeviceConnected,DeviceDisconnected etc through EventGrid.Please refer to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid and configure-subscription-for-iot-hub-events  here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-how-to-order-connection-state-events#configure-subscription-for-iot-hub-events/

Comment: Well, What i want is to use this service in mobile or web app. Where i want to acquire about my device is sending packets to cloud by providing devcie-id and connection string. Exactly like we do in device explorer. @Zainu

Comment: If you want to read the data like DeviceExplorer is then you can read it from EventHub compatible endpoint of IoTHub (example : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps).If you want to read historic data then you have few options like routing them to Azure Storage ,Azure Time Series Insights or Azure Data Explorer and then have a custom web-ap or mobile app to do the same but then there is a cost for the components you use.TSI example : http://learniotwithzain.com/2019/03/near-real-time-iot-data-exploration-using-azure-time-series-insights/

Comment: But if you are only interested in Device Events part then EventGrid integration can help.Please create an EventGrid Subscription for IoT Hub and then select the Events  (prob Device Connected,DeviceTelemetry,Device Disconnected in your case ) .Further you can provide the Endpoint Details where you want to route the data which can be EventHub,ServiceBus Queue]Topic,WebHook or Storage.Then have custom application  to read it from the Endpoint.

Comment: But Could i be able to use those Eventhub compatible end point in mobile application? @Zainu

Comment: Sorry I don't have knowledge on mobile applications but looks like Xamarin framework for mobile application does support Event-hub so you can check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your needs such as pushing a telemetry data to the Mobile App (Android, etc.), basically two patterns can be used for consuming a telemetry data from the Azure IoT Hub.

The following screen snippets show these patterns:

[image]

In the first pattern the telemetry data are consumed (Pull-up) by *EventHubTrigger* function and then pushed to the Azure *SignalRService* for delivering to the mobile client.

The second pattern is a true event driven pattern, where the Azure IoT Hub pushing (publishing) the telemetry data to the Azure Event Grid for its distributing in the Pub/Sub manner.

Note, that the integrator to the Web/Mobile App is the **Azure** **SignalRService**.